# how do i generate new refinerycms rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms

When i try to generate new refinerycms app, it tells that refinerycms-acts-as-indexed requires refinery-core 2.1.0 while rest of the gems depend on refinery-core 3.0.0.How to fix this?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "refinerycms-core":
```

In Gemfile:
    refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
        refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

```
refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms (~> 3.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-images (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
    refinerycms-core (= 3.0.0) ruby

refinerycms-wymeditor (>= 1.0.6, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (>= 3.0.0, ~> 3.0) ruby

refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (>= 1.0.0, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
  refinerycms-core (~> 2.1.0) ruby
    rake    db:create
```

Could not find gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (>= 1.0.0, ~> 1.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    generate    refinery:cms --fresh-installation 
Could not find gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed (>= 1.0.0, ~> 1.0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `rails new my_new_application -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge` from http://www.refinerycms.com/download